# How to determine if an object is an instance of a certain class in IBM Rules Designer/ODM?

Tags: rules, rule-engine, business-rules, jrules, ibm-odm

This may be an easy one, but I haven't found an easy way to determine in a rule that an object in working memory represented by an implemented interface is a specific class in IBM Rules Designer 8.8.1. For example, assuming `HousingPeriod` is an interface, if I have a definition that states:

```
definitions
    set 'the housing period' to a housing period...
```

And I want to follow that with a `where` clause that further refines the collection of objects that implement `HousingPeriod` as one of a list of implementing classes, say `CollegeHousingPeriod` and `InternshipHousingPeriod`, how could I do that? Something like:

```
        where this housing period is a college housing period
```

or

```
        where any of the following is true:
            - this housing period is a college housing period
            - this housing period is an internship housing period,
```

doesn't seem to work. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no built in way to query the type of an object. Instead I see two possible ways to get the desired result:

Create a virtual BOM entry with a custom B2X-mapping for each of your implementing classes. In the B2X-Mapping, you implement the necessary Java code to compare the object type and return a boolean. Verbalization would be something like `{1} is a college housing period`. This obviously only works if you know the objects before and there are not too many of them.

Option two is to not create different objects but to use a seperate attribute to distinguish housing period types. The verbalization would then be something like `where the type of this housing period is college housing`. With this approach you’d have to change the interface of your rules project, which might not be possible for you.